# Assign users to a group in Google Cloud Identity Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-identity, google-identity-toolkit

Is there a way to assign users to a group in Google Cloud Identity Platform.
For example : I have 5 users in my Google Cloud Identity Platform. Now I want to group all these 5 together so that in future I can assign the roles to the group and everyone in the group will have that permission.

Answer (score 1):

GCIP provides Authentication, not Authorization.  It is the Google Cloud version of Firebase Authentication, using the same client SDKs, but with more features in the backend, such as Multi-Factor Authentication, Multi-tenancy and Blocking Functions.

You cannot assign roles/ groups to GCIP users.  The way that I'd recommend is to use a database to store the users (using the `uid`) and assign the roles here.  You can then add these roles into the Custom Claims (GCIP) of the user.

### Writing custom claims

If you use Cloud Firestore, you can trigger a Cloud Function, whenever a user's document is updated, to write Custom Claims to GCIP, which can be read by your client application / REST API.

This post may help https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-group-based-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-72859cdec8f6

Answer (score -1):

There are Different ways to create a group and assign users to a group.

1.**Use Admin Console to create a group**

- create a new group from the console
- add group members to the newly created group

2.**Use google Groups**

I am attaching the public documentation for creation of groups and adding users to the groups.

[create groups and assign users to group](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9400082?hl=en)

[Using google groups](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9303222#2.1)